# Highcharts series data array bigger than it should be

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I simplified my code to show the problem as easy as I could. Here is part of my code that I use to create my HighCharts:

```
    $('#myChart').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {

            events: {
                load: function () {
                     // Here I have length 3, but it should be 2
                     for (i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++)
                     ...
                },
            },
        },

        ...
        ...
        // returnVal is a valid object with length 2
        series: returnVal;

    });
```

returnVal is a proper object, which has 2 data series inside (its length is 2). Something like this:

```
{
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    yAxis: 0,
    validData
},
{
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    yAxis: 1,
    validData
},
```

However, when the load: method is executed, this.series.length is 3 (there is additional series inside).

This is how the last series looks like in the debugger (data array is empty):

[image: last series object]

Is this only my case? What can be the cause?

Comment: Could you please share your example on jsfiddle with the data?

Comment: Highstock chart has additional series in [navigator](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock) - the series is registered in chart's `series` array. If this info doesn't resolve your problem, then please provide a live example, like JSFiddle.